# PDF Text positioning

Tags: pdf

Considering following operator sequence:

```
Tf: R8 9.96
Tm: 0 1.00057 -1 0 105.12 60.3506
TJ: line 1:

Tf: R8 9.96
Tm: 0 1.00057 -1 0 105.12 95.9906
TJ: value 1

Tm: 0 1.00057 -1 0 116.16 60.3505
TJ: line 2:

Tf: R8 9.96
Tm: 0 1.00057 -1 0 116.16 124.551
TJ: value 2

Tm: 0 1.00057 -1 0 127.2 60.3507
TJ: line 3:

Tf: R8 9.96
Tm: 0 1.00057 -1 0 127.2 106.671
TJ: value 3

Tm: 0 1.00057 -1 0 138.24 60.3508
TJ: line 4:

Tf: R8 9.96
Tm: 0 1.00057 -1 0 138.24 112.791
TJ: value 4
```

PDF displays it as:

```
line 1: value 1
line 2: value 2
line 3: value 3
line 4: value 4
```

Referencing to PDF documentation matrix consist of [a b c d e f], where e = Tx and f = Ty

From first two command blocks (which gives first line of text) I noticed that Tx and Ty actually switched places. 105.12 stays same which should state vertical position.

PDF reference also says about rotation:

> Rotations are produced by [ cos θ sin θ −sin θ cos θ 0 0 ], which has
>   the effect of rotating the coordinate system axes by an angle θ
>   counterclockwise.

Seems to be because of that Tx changes vertical position and Ty changes horizontal as sin(90) = 1 cos(0) = 0. Meaning 90 counterclockwise

[image: Effects of coordinate transformations]
Questionы:

1. Why increasing e (Tx) which considering rotation changes vertical position in actual PDF document lines go in correct order? According to Translation e (Tx) should descend.
2. Why letters and words are not rotated? Only e (Tx) and f (Ty) switched and that is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only consider text matrix settings. You don't tell us about the current transformation matrix at the time of those text objects, and neither do you tell us about the page rotation value.

Considering your observations I would assume the page globally is rotated 90° clockwise.

This would explain why your 90° counterclockwise rotated text appears upright (your second question).

Furthermore with that page rotation the x axis would be vertical with coordinate values rising downwards answering your first question.

**Some references**

> **Rotate** - integer - *(Optional; inheritable)* The number of degrees by which the page
>   shall be rotated clockwise when displayed or printed. The value
>   shall be a multiple of 90. Default value: 0.
>
> *(Table 30 – Entries in a page object - [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*
>
> CTM - array - The current transformation matrix, which maps positions from
>   user coordinates to device coordinates (see 8.3, "Coordinate
>   Systems"). This matrix is modified by each application of the
>   coordinate transformation operator, cm. Initial value: a matrix
>   that transforms default user coordinates to device
>   coordinates.
>
> *(Table 52 – Device-Independent Graphics State Parameters - [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*